# How to structure input parameter to object in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple Express API here.
When the user submits the chain param I want to convert the parameter to an object.
Depending on the input the object will have different values
Right now I just have a bunch of if statements stacked

Is there a better practice solution to implement this as this is quite clunky?

```
app.get('/gettokens/:chain/:address', async(req, res) => {
    const address = req.params.address;
    let chain = req.params.chain;

    if (chain == 'bsc') {
        chain = {
            moralis: 'bsc',
            coingecko: 'binance-smart-chain'
        }
    }

    if (chain == 'eth') {
        chain = {
            moralis: 'eth',
            coingecko: 'ethereum'
        }
    }

    if (chain == 'avax') {
        chain = {
            moralis: 'avalanche',
            coingecko: 'avalanche'
        }
    }

    if (chain == 'matic') {
        chain = {
            moralis: 'matic',
            coingecko: 'polygon-pos'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe a switch statement is what you're looking for? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: @david Ahh, that would be a bit cleaner I suppose. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a constant object

```js
const chainDef = {
     bsc: {  
                 moralis: ‘bsc’,
                 coingecko: ‘binance-smart-chain’
       } ,
    …
}

// you should validate `req.params.chain` before doing this
const chain = chainDef[req.params.chain]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use some configuration object to handle it

like this

```js
const config = {
  bsc: {
    moralis: 'bsc',
    coingecko: 'binance-smart-chain'
  },
  eth: {
    moralis: 'eth',
    coingecko: 'ethereum'
  },
  avax: {
    moralis: 'avalanche',
    coingecko: 'avalanche'
  },
  matic: {
    moralis: 'matic',
    coingecko: 'polygon-pos'
  }

}


const fallback = {
    moralis: 'something',
    coingecko: 'something'
  }
  
  
  const getChain = (key) => config[key] || fallback
  
  console.log(getChain('matic'))
  console.log(getChain('not defined'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define an object with all your different values and use the expected `req.params.chain` as keys:

```
const ChainObjs = {
  bsc: {
    moralis: 'bsc',
    coingecko: 'binance-smart-chain'
  },
  eth: {
    moralis: 'eth',
    coingecko: 'ethereum'
  },
  ...
}
```

And then you can get the correct value like this

```
app.get('/gettokens/:chain/:address', async(req, res) => {
  let chain = ChainObjs[req.params.chain]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As david suggested, you can use a [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

```js
/*
app.get('/gettokens/:chain/:address', async(req, res) => {
    const address = req.params.address;
    let chain = splitChain(req.params.chain); 
}
*/

function splitChain(value) {
  let coingecko
  switch (value) {
    case 'bsc':
      coingecko = 'binance-smart-chain'
      break;
    case 'eth':
      coingecko = 'ethereum'
      break;
    case 'avax':
      coingecko = 'avalanche'
      break;
    case 'matic':
      coingecko = 'polygon-pos'
      break;
    default:
      coingecko = null
      break;
  }
  return {
    moralis: value,
    coingecko: coingecko
  }
}

console.log(splitChain('bsc'))
console.log(splitChain('eth'))
console.log(splitChain('avax'))
console.log(splitChain('wrong-value'))
```